# booting from linux live dvd - no matter what kind - shuts the display off

Tags: livecd

I tried Knoppix and Ubuntu Live DVD's. After a couple of minutes, the display goes off! It says "Entering Power Save Mode". I can hear the really loud fans! The computer is still pretty much running.

If I start windows normally, the fans slow down after a little bit. In the case of Knoppix/Ubuntu, fans never slow down and the display goes off. Is something heating up really bad inside?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your graphics card isn't being detected properly. Try safe graphics mode from the boot menu. I think it's on the f4 option.